# Tag creation request: deezer-api

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-creation

I've been requested to create the [deezer-api](/questions/tagged/deezer-api) tag on Stack Overflow.

- Sample question title: `"Deezer API : Get the current logged user information"`
- Sample question body: `"How can I get the current information for an logged user?"`

Before proceeding I would like to ask for the community's opinion on this matter. Do you think that would be an appropriate content for SO?

Comment: Do we need `deezer-api` when we already have [deezer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deezer)?

Comment: -1: We really don't need both deezer and deezer-api; the existing tag has only two questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't notice that we already have the [deezer](/questions/tagged/deezer) tag.  We don't really need both.

---

<strike>I think it's okay to create the tag.</strike>  It looks like there are already several questions about [Deezer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=deezer) coming from several different users, so it's not just one user trying to astroturf by seeding SO with Q&A on the service.

Comment: Alright Bil, thanks for confirming this. It looks like the `deezer-api` tag has no place on Stack Overflow.